# File Upload Control Suddenly not working

Tags: .net, file-upload

I have a .net 2010 app I'm writing. In it, I have a standard file upload control. When I click the upload button, it goes through some code to display the image. This is in test so I've only been doing it local and it has been working fine. Suddenly, it doens't work and keeps trying to hit the network. Error: You're not connected to a network. Further, though this occurs when I click the Upload button, it won't let me debug.

Comment: too few details. is this ASP.NET web application? Can you show us the code you are using to upload the file to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Post your part of code which is giving error.
and check your **folder permission** where you are storing files.